# Print/Import all web page source data using vba

Tags: vba, excel, dom

I have code below which imports only part of source code into sheet. I want all source code as it is.`Sub GetSourceCode()

```
Dim ie As Object

Dim str As String
Dim arr

str = Sheets("sheet2").Range("I1").Value
Set ie = CreateObject("INTERNETEXPLORER.APPLICATION")

ie.Navigate "https://tiweb.industrysoftware.automation.com/prdata/cgi-bin/n_prdata_index.cgi?"
ie.Visible = False

Do Until ie.ReadyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop

ie.Document.getelementsbyname("pr_numbers")(0).Value = str
Application.SendKeys ("~")

Do Until ie.ReadyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop


Worksheets("Download_PRdata2").Activate

arr = Split(ie.Document.body.outertext)
Worksheets("Download_PRdata2").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arr) + 1, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(arr)
```

End Sub`

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can refer the below code

```
' Fetch Entire Source Code

Private Sub HTML_VBA_Excel()
Dim oXMLHTTP As Object
Dim sPageHTML As String
Dim sURL As String

'Change the URL before executing the code
sURL = "http://www.google.com"

'Extract data from website to Excel using VBA
Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
oXMLHTTP.Open "GET", sURL, False
oXMLHTTP.send
sPageHTML = oXMLHTTP.responseText

'Get webpage data into Excel
' If longer sourcecode mean, you need to save to a external text file or somewhere,
' since excel cell have some limits on storing max characters

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1) = sPageHTML

MsgBox "XMLHTML Fetch Completed"

End Sub
```

Source : http://www.vbausefulcodes.in/usefulcodes/get-data-or-source-code-from-webpage-using-excel-vba.php

Hope this will be useful to you!

Comment: My web page may have large information which can not be saved into cell. Also I wanted to insert data into webpage and then import data. Right now I am manually saving source code to some location and then importing it with macro. I wanted macro that will import whole data somehow with inserting pr_numbers from cell into web page and import source code of displayed page.

Answer (score 1):

you can save source code in a text file like this. add the below function instead of this line **ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1) = sPageHTML**

```
Createtextfile (sPageHTML)
```

and add this below function after End Sub.

```
Sub Createtextfile(sPageHTML)

Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim oFile As Object
strPath = "E:\test.txt"
Set oFile = fso.Createtextfile(strPath)
oFile.WriteLine sPageHTML
oFile.Close
Set fso = Nothing
Set oFile = Nothing

End Sub
```

Change the location where you want to save.

Comment: Nice, it's almost what I wanted but tried with original code(mine) as I wanted to insert text from cell to web page and then go ahead and save source code of that page. Can you help me in this context?

Comment: Did anyone look at this?